# Heyzap all ad networks in off state even after integrating all 3rd party ad networks

Tags: heyzap

I downloaded **Hezyap** latest version **10.0.9** and followed the documentation to integrate the following 3rd party ad networks

- **AdColony**
- **AppLovin**
- **Chartboost**
- **Vungle**
- **UntiyAds**
- **Admob**

I've created app for each ad networks in their respective admin portal and configured all necessary details in Heyzap admin portal. I then downloaded Heyzap sdk and placed in Unity project, took build and published a development build for Android

When I launch app, I got a test suite screen with all ad networks in off state. Please see the attached screenshot. But, for all configured ad networks, SDK Available is ON ( green color) , but "Configuration Not Present" and "SDK Failed to Start" in red color

[image]
[image]

Do I have to make any more changes ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you email support@heyzap.com with your Heyzap account name and app bundle identifier, we can look into this for you. We're sorting out a bug on our side today that may be causing this, but we need a bit more information to solve it, so that'd be helpful.

(In general, this error would mean that credentials are missing for this network on the dashboard, but I think in your case, today, it is an error on our end).

source: I'm an engineer at Heyzap.

Comment: thx for the quick reply, I will send all the required information to support. I have to submit a game tomorrow and I need to sort it out ASAP

Comment: I just sent an email. Pls check and let me know ASAP

Comment: @manroe Look's like I have similar problem configuring Unity Ads. Dashboard is configured properly (tested on project based on older Heyzap SDK (no 9.)) but on SDK 10. "SDK Available" - green, "Configuration present" - green, "SDK Failed to start" - red.

Comment: @Pawel, send them your account name and bundle identifier... They solved the issue for my account and its working now

Comment: Thanks, mate :) I'll.